# spring-mvc activiti dependency implementation

Tags: java, maven, jsp, tomcat, activiti

Error trace:
main INFO Cannot initialize scripting support because this JRE does not support it. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/odysseus/el/util/SimpleResolver

```
main INFO Cannot initialize scripting support because this JRE does not support it. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/odysseus/el/util/SimpleResolver
at org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.JuelScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(JuelScriptEngineFactory.java:128) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager.<init>(ScriptManager.java:100)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:287)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:627)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:700)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:717)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:272) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:245)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:176)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:666) 
at com.StanWeb.ui.main.UIlogger.<init>(UIlogger.java.23)
at com.StanWeb.ui.main.UIlogger.getLogger(UIlogger.java.73)
at com.StanWeb.rmt.RMTWSCreate.CreateRMTWSvc(CreateRMTWSvc.java.173)
at com.StanWeb.rmt.RMTWSCreate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b3a8785a.CGLIB$CreateRMTWSvc$11(<generated>)
at com.StanWeb.rmt.RMTWSCreate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9bbcdb0a.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
at com.StanWeb.rmt.RMTWSCreate$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b3a8785a.CreateRMTWSvc(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) 
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291) 
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909).
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) 
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.Java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start Internal (StandardServer.java:930)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.odysseus.el.util.SimpleResolver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1364) 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1187)
...71 more
main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 122 plugins
main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory 
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.48\webapps\examples] has finished in [3,374] ms
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory 
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.48)webapps\host-manager] 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARS during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log 
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.48\webapps host-manager] has finished in [2,755] ms 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory 
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.48\webapps\manager]
org.apache.Jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars 
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARS during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.48\webapps\manager] has finished in [2,761] ms
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory 
INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.48\webapps\ROOT]
org.apache. jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars 
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARS during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplication Initializer types detected on classpath 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.48\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [2,301] ms
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"]
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [176785] milliseconds
```

Trace

```
main DEBUG juel version: 1.0, language: JSP 2.1 EL, threading: MULTITHREADED, compile: true, names: [juel], factory class: org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.JuelScriptEngineFactory
main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn version: 1.8.0_65, language: ECMAScript, threading: Not Thread Safe, compile: true, names: [nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript], factory class: jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory
main DEBUG BeanShell Engine version: 1.0, language: BeanShell, threading: MULTITHREADED, compile: true, names: [beanshell, bsh, java], factory class: bsh.engine.BshScriptEngineFactory
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http pattern="/resource/**" security="none" />
<http entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true"> 
<intercept-url pattern="/web/**" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/j_spring security_check" access="isAnonymous()" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/web/j_spring security_check" access="isAnonymous()" /> 
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('USER_ADMINISTRATION', 'IT_SUPPORT')" />
<logout success-handler-ref="CustomLogoutHandler" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
<access-denied-handler error-page="/web/Index.html" /> 

<custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" /> 
<custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter"/> 
<custom-filter position="LAST" ref="appFilter" />
<session-management session-authentication strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/web/SessionExpired.html" /> 
</http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> 
    <authentication-provider ref="CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy"/>
    <beans:bean id="CustomLogoutHandler" class="com.StanWeb.auth.CustomLogoutHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="CustomAuthenticationProvider" class="com.StanWeb.auth.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.StanWeb.auth.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/> 
    <beans:bean id="appFilter" class="com.StanWeb.ui.filter.ApplicationFilter"/>
    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.StanWeb.auth.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

    <beans:bean id="redirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SimpleRedirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy">
       <beans:constructor-arg name="invalidSessionUrl" value="/web/Index.html" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" /> 
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionInformationExpiredStrategy" ref="redirectSessionInformationExpiredStrategy" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" /> 
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"/> 
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="username"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="password"/>
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
<beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:list>
        
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" /> 
        <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="false" />
        </beans:bean> 
        
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy"> 
        </beans:bean>
        
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
        </beans:beans>
    </beans:list>
</beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:beans>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

    <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
    <beans:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/web/Index.html" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

While running my application I am getting error message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/odysseus/el/util/SimpleResolver.

I am using Spring-mvc version 5 and Tomcat version 9.

Please help

Here is my pom.xml https://github.com/mansreeal/StanWeb/blob/main/pom.xml

Comment: It seems that Activiti hardcodes the usage of JUEL as EL implementation. Considering also your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68028883/11748454), try restoring `juel-api` and `juel-impl`, but keep `juel-spi` excluded. BTW: you should tag your questions with `activiti`, since the errors concern primarily this library.

Comment: thank you PiotrP.Karwasz, the issue not is not appearing now but I am getting j_spring_security_check under spring-security.xml file 404-page error message.

Comment: I have an issue with my application, after providing the credentials on the login page and submitting the page, it is not redirected to the target page instead it is struck in the page -> http://localhost:8080/StanWeb/j_spring_security_check. Please let me know whether the activiti dependency will cause this redirection issue.